# Overwrite :after & : before classes content of Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-class

I want to overwrite the following CSS

```
  .navbar:before{
    display: table;
    content: " ";
  }
```

and remove any content possible in the before or after files. It's creating unnecessary space between my navbar and left panel.
I tried giving that class an

```
content: none !important;
```

But it was not getting overwritten.
Is there any way we can overwrite this? I am on the latest Bootsrap version.

Answer (score 7):

For overriding it this would be enough:

```
.navbar:before {
    content: none !important;
}
```

If that doesn't help you can also try :

```
.navbar:before {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This would hide the element. But if you don't see the properties being overridden (check that with developer tools inspector) then i would search if those css rules are even added to the page.

Also it's possible that something else is causing the space.

Important would override even inline properties added with `style=""`. Here are some reads about specificity:

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

If `content: none` does not work try `display: none`.

And about it not getting overwritten, have you had a look in devtools? Clearly something is causing it to **not** get overwritten, would be good to have a direct look ;)